# PushTopic record not getting copied over while creating/refreshing the full sandbox

Tags: sandbox, streaming-api, sandbox-refresh, pushtopic

We create trial orgs from environment hub with managed packages and related configuration. This configuration also includes a PushTopic record. However while creating/refreshing full sandboxes from this trial org, PushTopic record is not getting copied over to sandbox.

Is this expected behavior?

Can someone please provide their insights here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Raised a case with Salesforce and they came back saying that this is a known issue. Below is the link provided by them.
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Y1sAAE

Not sure if they have any plan to fix it in near future. Hope it helps to people coming across this.